# MSMQ replay message randomly why?

Tags: msmq, com+

I have 2 COM+ component from which first place message in the MSMQ and initializes other COM+. Then second COM+ application process the message from MSMQ and message gets removed from queue. I am getting issue of same message replay 2 times for some requests randomly.

Does anyone know the reason why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are performing a two-stage process.

1. Peek message to get the data
2. Receive message to delete the message

The first instance of the second COM+ application hasn't yet received the message before a second instance of the second COM+ application peeks the same message, resulting in multiple processing.

If that's the case, better approach is to use a Transactional Receive instead of Peek/Receive. Assuming your OS supports that.